# How to have l and h at the boundary of the window shift only one column, when wrap is off?

Tags: cursor-movement, scrolling, wrapping

How can I have <kbd>h</kbd> and <kbd>l</kbd> move the viewport only by one column when they go beyond the left and right borders when `nowrap` is active?

Comment: I know you can scroll horizontally by a column at a time with `zl` and `zh` but it doesn't move the cursor. Does that work for you? Not sure if you can do it with cursor moving. But a mapping to do so should be doable. `nnoremap zl zl<right>`

Comment: @BLayer, at least it allows a kind of workaround. I could map `h` to do `zh` followed by `h`, and similarly for `l`. I'll try it out while waiting for answers.

Comment: Exactly what I had in mind.

Comment: Oooh, maybe `'sidescroll'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply do this:

```
set sidescroll=1
```

[`'sidescroll'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27ss%27) controls "the minimal number of columns to scroll horizontally". So with a value of 1 `h` and `l` will shift the screen one column at a time.

Side note: the commands [`zh`](https://vimhelp.org/scroll.txt.html#zl) and [`zl`](https://vimhelp.org/scroll.txt.html#zh) will shift the screen a column at a time but they don't move the cursor. If, for some reason, you couldn't or didn't want to change `'sidescroll'` you could do something like `nnoremap zh zh<left>` to achieve the same effect.

Comment: Simeone said _someone_ :P

Comment: LOL, hey what can I say? :)

Comment: what can _I_ say. Thank youuu